# double royal marriage and a roundhouse

Tags: pinochle

How do you score a double royal marriage and a roundhouse if you are playing double deck or triple deck pinochle?

I got that tonight playing and wanted to score it 50 points, thirty for the double royal marriage and the 20 for the roundhouse instead of 24 to subtract the trump marriage from the roundhouse.

I got shot down like I was nuts and they only wanted to let me have six points for the roundhouse.

Answer (score 1):

A roundhouse normally doesn't have any special scoring involved; it is simply a nickname for a set of other things that score, that happen to add up to 24. In your case:

Double Royal Marriage: 8
Queens around: 6
Kings around: 8
3 Marriages: 6

This adds up to 28 (which is 24 for the roundhouse, plus 4 for the extra royal marriage).

Thus, by default rules, you should have scored 28.

[There are variants](https://www.pagat.com/marriage/pindd.html#variations) that some people play where a roundhouse does score higher than 24. However, you and your playgroup would have to discuss and agree to such a thing before the game; as it isn't part of the standard rules.

> Roundhouse
>
> > This consists of a king and a queen of each suit. It normally scores 24: royal marriage + 3 marriages + kings around + queens around. However some players give a roundhouse a higher score of 32. Some score a roundhouse with a run as 39 (24 + 15, allowing the royal marriage to contribute to the roundhouse as well as being part of the run). Some score a double roundhouse as 240 (it should normally be 160 = 8 + 3*4 + 80 + 60).